# Calling Perl from a shell script, how do I pass a return value from Perl to the shell?

Tags: perl

I'm successfully calling a Perl script from a shell script. Now I want to pass a return value from the Perl script indicating whether it was successful or not to the shell script. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply exit the Perl script with the appropriate exit value.

`exit $exit_value;`

`exit 0;`

`if ($problem) { exit 1 }`

In the shell script you'll have the usual `$?` to check the return value.