# Return value from a Perl script

Tags: perl, return-value

Is it possible to return a value (or hashes or arrays) from a Perl script invoked by another?

#### File *caller.pl*

```
printf("%d", system("callee.pl"));
```

#### File *callee.pl*

```
if(<Went good>)
{
    return(1);
}
else
{
    return(100);
}
```

Comment: For returning an exit code from a Perl script (e.g., to an invoking script for a pass/fail condition), see e.g. *[Calling Perl from a shell script, how do I pass a return value from Perl to the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462173)*. Though, given the date and number of votes, the canonical question is probably another question. *This* question turns up in a search with "return value Perl script".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to wrap callee.pl in a 'sub {}' then require then script and call it. You can then treat the sub as a normal procedure.

#### File *caller.pl*

```
require("callee.pl");
printf("%d", callee());
```

#### File *callee.pl*

```
sub callee {
    if(<Went good>)
    {
        return(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(100);
    }
}

1;
```

Comment: And if you can't modify the contents of callee.pl, you should be able to do `sub callee { do 'callee.pl' }` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Just make sure callee.pl ends with a [True Value](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) such as `1;` Otherwise the require() function may fail.

Comment: @khinkle Thanks, I completely forgot

Answer (score 0):

`system` will only give an exit status, which is not a return value.
Just print to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) from the callee and use backticks to capture in the caller.